# Will Ubuntu go faster with Ubuntu 2D instead of Ubuntu 3D?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, performance

I tried both Ubuntu 3D and 2D, and it looks as if it goes fast in both, except when I open the dash menu (in 3D), it goes too slow. If I resize the Dash, it goes a little slowly, but not too much.

Is it normal? Will Ubuntu run faster with Ubuntu 2D (I don't like 2D, I like much more Ubuntu 3D)?

Comment: You should try, and let us all know. :~)

Comment: I just want to know if **theorically** it should go faster or not

Answer (score 2):

I agree Unity 2d is faster. But essencially depends on how much memory do you have. I have solved an issue with my keyboard by switching to unity 2d. I had my keyboard taking up to four seconds before it showed what I typed, at first use - subsequently everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, Ubuntu 2D could also be **slower** (no hardware acceleration, all the work is made by the CPU via software).

Pratically, if you're not running your Ubuntu on this [www.youtube.com/watch?v=nm0POwEtiqE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nm0POwEtiqE&feature=player_embedded) (that's fun, take a look at it) it will be **faster**.

Comment: Good choice..try also XFCE (xubuntu) for a complete and lightweight desktop environment!

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, the 2D goes faster. It also consumes less power, so I prefer 2D more.

Answer (score 0):

Essential yes, your graphics card won't have to work as hard in 2d compared to 3d, which should quicken responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Graphically, it will go much quicker.   Computationally?  There's no real difference, if your CPU is being used as a fallback then you WILL notice the difference.  But if all the work is being done by your GPU (graphics processor) then you won't.

Answer (score 0):

on my eee pc ro051bx (amd c-60 1.3mhz 1gb ram) unity 3d & unity 2d work the same speed.
unity 3d is somewone say just a compiz pluggin, and unity 2d is combination of unity 2d panel, unity 2d launcher and unity 2d places, so unity 2d run multiple processes and is compicated then unity 3d.
you can run every part of unity 2d independed foristence: 
you can run in openbox/gnome (after install openbox you get openbox and openbox/gnome session in lightDM), unity 2d panel and cairo-dock if you did't like unity launcher, and run compiz in that.

also, you can run unity 2d launcher in gnome-shell if you want...

unity 3d and unity 2d is complitle diferent things...

Answer (score 0):

for me is faster, i set more sensitive in settings also i switch off animation in /usr/share/unity-2d/spread/utils.js to "var transitionDuration = 0" and my intel integrate grapics support openGL so via dconf i set to use openGL and is working very fast.